# how to determine slo mo video in UIImagePickerController ios

Tags: ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I have one scenario with `UIImagePickerController` is how do I check that user is selected slo-mo video or normal video in iOS.

I have try to determine from videos FPS and BPS but I'm not able to achieve my result.

Please help to find that user has selected normal video or slo-mo video from camera roll.

Thanks in advance