# Can we programmatically convert slo-mo videos to normal speed keeping the 240FPS intact?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I want to convert the slo-mo video picked from the iPhone's Gallery into my app and play it with normal speed at 240 FPS. Currently it plays with slow speed with 30 FPS.

There is a manual workaround as given [here](https://www.igeeksblog.com/convert-slow-motion-video-to-normal-video-on-iphone-ipad/)

But I want to do it programmatically after picking Video from Gallery.

Also, Is there any way to detect if it is a slo-mo video or normal video? This question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934251/how-to-determine-slo-mo-video-in-uiimagepickercontroller-ios) but there is no answer to it.

Comment: You can manually faster your video.same question is here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536308/increase-the-maximum-play-rate-of-avplayer

Comment: you can read more at https://medium.com/@xcadaverx/avfoundation-cmtimemapping-c3521d4da6b1